# Jags gets wired, returns redefining node errer occasionally, due to different data

Tags: jags

I created my code based on this : 
http://users.aims.ac.za/~mackay/BUGS/Manual05/Examples1/node29.html

Now I use different seeds to simulate data. It is strange enough that some seeds give me a redefining node dN[1,1] on line 18 error, while others do not. Could someone help please? BTW why is dN[1,1] on line 18 at the first place? How does Jags count lines?

error message :
"
RUNTIME ERROR:

Compilation error on line 18.

Attempt to redefine node dN[1,1]
"

```
  bugsmodel <- "
  # Set up data
  data{
    for(i in 1:N) 
    {
      for(j in 1:bigt) 
      {
      Y[i,j] <- step(obs.t[i] - t[j] + eps)
      dN[i, j] <- Y[i, j] * step(t[j + 1] - obs.t[i] - eps) * fail[i]
      }
    }
  }
  # Model
  model
  {
  for(i in 1:N){
    betax[i,1] <- 0
    for(k in 2:(p+1)){
    betax[i,k] <- betax[i,k-1] + beta[k-1]*x[i,k-1]
    }
  }
  for(j in 1:bigt) {
    for(i in 1:N) {
    dN[i, j] ~ dpois(Idt[i, j]) # Likelihood
    Idt[i, j] <- Y[i, j] * exp(betax[i,p+1]) * dL0[j] # Intensity
    }
    dL0[j] ~ dgamma(mu[j], c)
    mu[j] <- dL0.star[j] * c # prior mean hazard
  }
  c <- 0.001
  r <- 0.1
  for (j in 1 : bigt) {
    dL0.star[j] <- r * (t[j + 1] - t[j])
  } 
  for(k in 1:p){
    beta[k] ~ dnorm(0.0,0.000001)
  }
  }"
```

Comment: Are you including `dN` to the data list you supply to the model?

Comment: Hi M_Fidino, thank you for your comments. No I did not.    "data <- list(x=x,obs.t=y,t=t,bigt=bigt,N=n,fail=event,eps=1E-10,p=p)" and 
  "inits <-  function(){list( beta = rep(0,p), dL0 = rep(0.0001,bigt))}"  The wired part is the code works sometimes, but failed by other data.

Comment: is dN guaranteed to be non-negative integers?